# FQL accessing Friends Likes

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

How do I access friends likes with FQL? I can see it in the Graph API:

https://graph.facebook.com/1111111/likes

... but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in FQL.

Answer (score 4):

```
fql?q=SELECT uid, page_id from page_fan where uid IN(SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```

You can try this in your api explorer to get user friends likes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by querying [`url_like`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/) table:

```
SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id IN (
  SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
)
```

You cannot however get list of likes by friends for: photo, album, event, group, note, link, video, application, status, check-in, review, comment, post.

This info is located in [`like`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) table but to query it based on `user_id` you need `read_stream` permissions from that user...

EDIT: Added Graph API Explorer Example to easily preview this:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20url%20FROM%20url_like%20WHERE%20user_id%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me())

Comment: so I can't access Friends' likes with this? (The query returns no data.) Strange, considering I can get the info via the Graph API.

Comment: Actually there is nothing wrong with doing it with Graph API, I'm suggesting using FQL only for things yet missing in Graph API...

Comment: Just checked and the query above do produce correct results. Are you sure you have `friends_likes` permission granted and have valid `access_token`? Check it with Graph API explorer using your application, use "Get Access Token" button to ensure required permissions granted...

Comment: Yes and yes. And again, my question is in regards to FQL, not the Graph API.

Comment: What I checked was FQL query I've posted in answer, and it works as expected. What did you get in response! Again, check your query in GraphExplorer using path `/fql` and specifying query as `q` parameter!